# Count how many errors with Ember-Validations?

Tags: validation, ember.js

I would like to display the count of validation errors to my user.

It is to implement a message like "You have X error(s) left" next to the submit button.

Is there a way to do this ?

Edit :

I am using [ember-validations](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations) `2.0.0-alpha.1` and ember `1.8.0` in the context of a controller (without ember data).

If I try the solution of Sam:

```
this.get('errors.length') // result is [], an empty array
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `errors` key holds an object, not an array. Each key of this object refers to a property on your model and points to an array of error messages, so you can do things like `this.get('errors.firstName.length')`.

To find the total number of errors, you'd have to look through each of your model's properties and sum the number of errors for each one.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/luzesiyeqi/1/

---

EDIT:

The `.length` property of the `errors` object is returning an empty array because of this code: https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations/blob/master/addon/errors.js. Literally any key you access on the `errors` object will be initialized to an empty array.

---

EDIT 2:

Based on what you said in the comments about not wanting to loop through properties, you can do it in an alternative fashion by looking at the model's `validators` property. Check out this example:

```
numErrors: function () {
  var errorCounts = this.get('model.validators').mapBy('errors.length');
  return errorCounts.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b }, 0);
}.property('model.validators.@each.length')
```

I've updated the JSBin, too:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jucuxodaga/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hello, I know that the errors property holds an object, it is "errors.length" that holds an array (as I wrote), and this is very surprising for the very least. I assume there is a bug here, I will raise an issue then. I just thought I missed something. Your solution is (sorry!!) obvious, and I don't want to look through all the properties of my model to calculate the error count. In fact, I asked this question precisely to avoid this solution. However, thank you. And sorry, I can't accept.

Comment: With all due respect, you asked how to display the number of errors to the user, and I told you how to display then number of errors to the user. If you want the answer to a different question, you should ask that question instead. And if you have arbitrary constraints, e.g. "I don't want to look through the properties", then you need to put that in your question as well.

Comment: Ok. Maybe you're right I should have pointed out my constraint. On the other hand the need to repeat all the field names seems very error prone to me and as such a bad solution. Thanks you very much for your explanations and the final solution !! :-)

Answer (score -1):

If you're using [ember-validations](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations), this will be easy: `this.errors.length`.

Comment: That is what I would have expected, but the result of this.get('errors.length') is itself an array of 0 items (which is kind of strange).